# repeating operation against multiple lists

Tags: python

Let us assume the following lists:

```
totest=[2,4,5,3,6]
l1=[6,8,7,9,4]
l2=[3,12,21,30]
l3=[2,5]
```

And the following function:

```
def evalitem(x):
...detail....
```

I have to execute the function against the intersection of totest against all the other lists in a sequence unless there is an exception.
There is always the following option:

```
test1=set(totest)&set(l1)
try:
  for i in test1:
  evalitem(i)
except:
    return
test2=.....
```

But there should be a faster pythonic functional way to achieve this,with much better performance.
Do note that we go to evaluate test2 only if test1 does not raise an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
totest = set(totest)

for lst in l1, l2, l3:
    for item in totest.intersection(lst):
        evalitem(item)
```

If you don't know how to handle an exception (`except: return` doesn't count), there is no need to use `try...except` at all. Handle it in the code that *calls* the function in question.